# How to put every element of a avl into an array using C

Tags: c

I am trying to pass every element (string) of a AVL to an array using C. I try to do:

```
void inorderCli(clientes t,int index, char a[]){
  if (t != NULL){
    inorderCli(t->esq,index,a);
    strcpy(a[index],t->cli);
    index=index+5;
    inorderCli(t->dir,inde,a);
  }
}
```

```
typedef struct ctree{
    char cli[5];
    struct ctree *esq, *dir;
    int alt;
}* clientes;
```

I try to do this but it didn't work. Any suggestions for how it can be done?

Comment: Please clarify "it didn't work". What did you want to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: Is this cut'n'paste from the actual code? I ask because it doesn't look like it would compile. For example, this bit `inorderCli(t->dir,inde,a);` has misspelt `index`.

Comment: This will also copy the terminating `'\0'` for each string into `a`, if what you are trying to do is actually concatenate them.

Comment: This style for defining pointer types is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way.  `index` must be updated in the parent as well.

Try this method instead:

```
int inorderCli(clientes t, int index, char a[]) {
    if (t != NULL) {
      index = inorderCli(t->esq, index, a);
      if (a) strcpy(a + index, t->cli);
      index = inorderCli(t->dir, index + 5, a);
    }
    return index;
}
```

and call this function from your `main` like this:

```
int size = inorderCli(client_root, 0, NULL);
char *a = malloc(size);
inorderCli(client_root, 0, a);
```

Notice how calling with `NULL` computes the size needed for the output array.